# Insert different datas to different table from a single insert query in sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanted to insert different values to, two different sqlite tables from a single insert query.Can any one help me out...........

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do it in two lines?? Programme will execute one after another.

You can do something as below

```
dbHelper = new RdmsDbAdapter(SDCardVideoActivity.this);
dbHelper.open();
dbHelper.executeSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS videos(urls text)");
dbHelper.executeSQL("insert into videos values ('"+outputfilepathVideo+"', '"+IncidentFormActivity.incident_id+"')");
dbHelper.executeSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS audios(urls text)");
dbHelper.executeSQL("insert into audios values ('"+outputfilepathAudio+"', '"+IncidentFormActivity.incident_id+"')");
dbHelper.close();
```

Learn on how to handle `sqlite` with [Android here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Comment: from docs: `execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)
Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.`

Comment: @Selvin I know. Its a custom function I wrote for the ease of use. That's why I've given link to Vogella's tutorial which uses the standard methods.